Angular Graphql Codegen - Mutate issue
I'm currently facing an issue when I try to execute this simple mutation via GraphqlCodegen / Angular:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mutate')
    at _LoginService.signIn (login.service.ts:15:20)
    at _LoginComponent.onSubmit (login.component.ts:37:23)
    at LoginComponent_Template_button_click_30_listener (login.component.html:86:22)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.mjs:24697:16)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.mjs:24730:22)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.mjs:749:112)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)
    at core.mjs:14452:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:14452:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
Many thanks for your help

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { signInMutationService } from '../../../graphql/generated';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoginService {
  //private readonly JWT_TOKEN = 'JWT_TOKEN';
  //private loggedUser?: string;
  //private isAuthenticatedSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  private signInGQL: signInMutationService

  signIn(login: string, password: string) {

    this.signInGQL.mutate({
      authInput: {
        login,
        password
      }
    }).subscribe(({ data, errors, loading }) => {
      if (errors) {
        console.error('Error getting connection', errors);
      }
      if (data) {
        console.log('Data retrieved', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
      }
    })
  }

}

First, I don't really understand the meaning of this issue and how to fix it.
